# why this code is broken

Tags: c++

Im trying to erase an object from vector cointener.

My code is:

```
vector<Wezel <int> > wektor;

int main()
{

Wezel<int> parent = Wezel<int>(true,"p1",  1);
Wezel<int> child1 = Wezel<int>(true,"ch1", 2);
Wezel<int> child2 = Wezel<int>(true,"ch2", 3);
Wezel<int> child3 = Wezel<int>(true,"ch3", 4);
Wezel<int> child4 = Wezel<int>(true,"ch4", 5);

parent.addWezel(&child1);

child1.addWezel(&child2);

child3.addWezel(&parent);

child4.addWezel(&child1);

wektor.push_back(parent);
wektor.push_back(child1);
wektor.push_back(child2);
wektor.push_back(child3);
wektor.push_back(child4);


child4.substractWezel(&child1){
tablica->erase(remove(tablica->begin(), tablica->end(), *child), tablica- >end());
    }

  return 0;
 }
```

code from Wezel.h:

```
 template <class T>
 class Wezel
 {
 public:
    Wezel<T>& operator=(const Wezel<T>& obj);
    Wezel<T>  operator+(const Wezel<T>& obj);
    Wezel<T>& operator==(const Wezel<T>& obj);
 //   Wezel<T> operator!();

    Wezel(bool skierowany, string nazwa,  T wartosc)
    {
        this->tablica = new vector<Wezel<T> >[4];
        this->wartosc = wartosc;
        this->skierowany = skierowany;
        this->nazwa = nazwa;
    }

    Wezel(const Wezel &wezel){
        this->tablica = wezel.tablica;
        this->wartosc = wezel.wartosc;
        this->skierowany = wezel.skierowany;
        this->nazwa = wezel.nazwa;
    }



    ~Wezel<T>(){


    }
      T getWartosc(){
        return wartosc;
    }

    void setWartosc(T wartosc){
        this->wartosc = wartosc;
    }


    vector<Wezel<T> > getTablica(){
       return *tablica;
    }

    void setTablica(vector<Wezel<T> > *tablica){
        this->tablica = tablica;
    }

    void addWezel(Wezel<T> *child){

        if(getTablicaSize() == getTablicaMaxSize()){
            cout << "tablica pelna, nie mozna dodac wezla" << endl;
            return;
        }


        tablica->push_back(*child);

        if(!skierowany){
            if(child->getTablicaSize() == child->getTablicaMaxSize()){
                cout << "tablica pelna, nie mozna dodac wezla" << endl;
            return;
            }
            child->getTablica().push_back(*this);
         }

         }

      void substractWezel(Wezel *child){


     tablica->erase(tablica->begin()+1, *child);


    tablica->erase(remove(tablica->begin(), tablica->end(), *child), tablica->end());


    string getNazwa(){
        return this->nazwa;
    }


protected:
private:
    vector<Wezel<T> > *tablica = new vector<Wezel<T> >[4];
    T wartosc;
    bool skierowany;
    string nazwa;

    int getTablicaMaxSize(){
        return this->tablica->max_size();
    }

    int getTablicaSize(){
        return this->tablica->size();
    }

     };
    template <typename T>
    ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const Wezel<T>& obj)
    {
        return os << obj;
    }

    template <typename T>
    Wezel<T> Wezel<T>::operator + (const Wezel<T>& obj)
    {
    Wezel<T> tmp_obj = *this;
    tmp_obj.wartosc = tmp_obj.wartosc + obj.wartosc;
    tmp_obj.nazwa = tmp_obj.nazwa + obj.nazwa;
    return tmp_obj;

    }


    template <class T>

    Wezel<T>& Wezel<T>::operator = (const Wezel<T> & obj)

    {
        wartosc = obj.wartosc;
        nazwa = obj.nazwa;
        tablica = obj.tablica;
        skierowany = obj.skierowany;
        return *this;
    }
    template<class  T>
    Wezel<T>& Wezel<T>::operator==(const Wezel<T>& obj) { /* ... */ }

   #endif // WEZEL_H
```

and the Error shown in compiler is:

error: no match for 'operator!' in '!(& __first.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator**, std::vector > >())->Wezel::operator==((* & __value))'|

Please help.

Comment: Please be clearer: what are you trying to do and what is the whole compiler output?
Also, the last part of the code is missing.

Comment: my english is not very good. Im basically trying to erase the and object from vector.
just look the whole program would be easier
http://speedy.sh/ZGDXX/graf.rar

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

It says that `Wezel<int>::operator==` does not exist. And `std::remove` needs it to find what to remove.

Comment: so i need to overload == operator?

Comment: @notkink From `std::remove` documentation: _The function uses operator== to compare the individual elements_. So yes, you need to overload `operator==`

Comment: Absolutely. `template<typename T> Wezel<T>::operator==(const Wezel<T>& other) { /* ... */ }`

Comment: Ok , I did overload the == operator , but now i have 
 '|error: no match for 'operator!' in '!(& __first.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator*<Wezel<int>*, std::vector<Wezel<int> > >())->Wezel<T>::operator==<int>((* & __value))'|'

            I tried to overload ! operator too ,but it wouldnt work either

Comment: We will need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help you. The code you post on your question doesn't make sense.